# Foreach doesn't go through all items?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code:

```
       foreach (var item in ListView1.Items)
            {
                ListView1.Items.Remove(item);
                ListView21.Items.Add(item);
            }
```

the loop stops at half of the items?

Any idea?

EDIT

Well, maybe it's my mistake, I need to clarify that this is UltraListView control from Infrajistics, where I can't add item to another list unless I remove it or clone it from the original list.

But thanks, most of the comments regarding do not modify the list within the loop were correct, so this code works:

```
           foreach (var item in listView1.Items)
            {
                var i = item.Clone(true);
                listView2.Items.Add(i);
            }
            listView1.Items.Clear();
```

Thanks,

Comment: Moving items from list1 to list2!

Comment: CopyTo()/AddRange() + Clear() then

Comment: asp.net or winforms? I already added WinForms as the more likely candidate, but please correct it if that's wrong.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot modify iterated collection, it should die with exception (or in undefined behavior).
Try making a copy of the array:

```
   foreach (var item in ListView1.Items.ToArray())
   {
       ListView1.Items.Remove(item);
       ListView21.Items.Add(item);
   }
```

EDIT:

in fact, your example code can be achieved by writing:

```
ListView21.Items.AddRange(ListView1.Items);
ListView1.Items.Clear();
```

(which in fact isn't EXACTLY what you are doing, but gives the same result and I think it won't bother you having the same content in both listviews for a moment). The latter is supported since .NET2.0, first solution requires linq, and therefore .NET3.5.

Comment: Perhaps a bit nitpicking, but `ListView`'s `Items` does not have a `ToArray` method by itself.

Comment: Thanks, the first one can't work because there is no ToArray
I'll try the second one

Comment: It will work if you add a reference to LINQ, add a using-statement `using System.Linq` and (only if) you use .NET 3.5 or higher.

Comment: You can just add `Cast<ListViewItem>()` before `ToArray()` to get a generic `IEnumerable<T>` wrapping the `IEnumerable`.

Comment: My last edit covers situation, when first suggestion works. (.net 3.5, linq)

Answer (score 9):

You are modifying the collection you are looping through. Try using a `for` statement from top to bottom (from the item with the highest index to 0).

```
for (int i = ListView1.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    var item = ListView1.Items[i];
    ListView1.Items.Remove(item);
    ListView21.Items.Insert(0, item);
}
```

Comment: better:


int itemCount = ListView1.Items.Count;

for (int i = itemCount - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    var item = ListView1.Items[i];
    ListView1.Items.Remove(item);
    ListView21.Items.Insert(0, item);
}

Comment: Cool ans cham... I was hating my method to create new list to store removing items and all...

Answer (score 2):

It will cause a runtime exception, complaining that you cannot modify the collection while iterating through it. You have to use `for` loop instead.

```
for(int index = Items.Count; index > 0; index--)
{
    .......
    // use Add and RemoveAt
}
```

EDIT : As mentioned by others. If you just need to move items from one collection to the other. `AddRange` and `Clear` will be better.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any exception or error message? Looping in a collection and remove items from the same collection is always a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the WinForms list view control, so:

```
ListViewItem[] items = ListView1.Items.ToArray();
ListView1.Items.Clear();
ListView21.Items.AddRange(items);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why just not [CopyTo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.copyto.aspx) to new list and then [Clear()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.listviewitemcollection.clear.aspx) items?

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through all items, removing all of them, then adding them to another list. As others have commented, you cannot remove items from a list in a for-each. Why not looping through all items to add them to your other list, and then remove them all in one go?

```
foreach (var item in ListView1.Items)
{
    ListView21.Items.Add(item);
}
ListView1.Items.Clear();   // remove all
```

PS: is this an ASP.NET listview or a WinForms listview?

Answer (score -1):

That's because you're changing the collection inside the loop.
Use a normal for loop as follows:

```
for(int i=0; i < ListView1.Items.Count-1; i++)
{
       ListView21.Items.Add(ListView1.Items[i]);
       ListView1.Items.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Comment: Because Items is a collection, it will fix the index of items in the listview. Remove(0), shift all to begin, remove(1) will then remove item 3(original index of 2, now 1).

Comment: To fix this iterate over the collection from the last to the first item and it will work. `for (int i = ListView1.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)`. Further you have to insert at index zero instead of adding to the end to keep the correct order.